# C++ to QML - setting properties

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a Qt (4.7.4) application, which is a graphic terminal for other applications.
In QML I have defined Views with (named) controls.
In C++ I receive commands from applications which request to show a view with specified values for my controls. When the command comes, I use something like

```
myView = LoadTheNewViewIntoLoader(viewName);
QObject* ctrl = myView->findChild<QObject*>(ctrlName);
if(ctrl)
{
  ctrl->setProperty("caption", newCaption);
}
```

to update the control value (i.e. change text, image or whatever).

**Question**: How quick is such an operation? Or: How can I be sure that all of the properties have been applied to the controls?

The problem is that in C++ I create a semaphore for the action of loading view and setting all of the properties, but when there are many commands coming during stress test, I have feeling that the values do not have ehough time to propagate from C++ to QML and when I'm performing next command, the previous actions are still executing. In such a situation the controls disappear from the screen at all for some time and sometimes I get even the Segmentation Fault. This is easier to achieve for more complicated screens with big number of controls.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple your  design for performance / load handling.

Using SLOTS , SIGNALS

Let the C++ handle the logic and Qml the controls, viewer

Something like
    myView = LoadTheNewViewIntoLoader(viewName);

```
QObject* ctrl = myView->findChild<QObject*>(ctrlName);

if (ctrl)
{
    emit sgnShowcaption("newCaption");
}
```

Handle in qml this signal
and set
.label = str (str shall be in the signal you caught)

Comment: So each time I find the control on the current view (which sometimes may be even hundred times during one ShowView operation), I should connect to its slot and then emit the signal? And this will help my performance/stability problems?